# Laravel 9 $model->replicate() is not immutable

Tags: php, laravel, clone, laravel-9

it seems Laravel 9 $model->replicate() does not create immutable instance.
Am I right or not? Cause if I make changes on original model it changes also the replica instance. How to make an immutbale clone from Laravel model?

Comment: From some local testing, `$instance = Model::first();`, then `$second = $instance->replicate()`. If I then do `$instance == $second`, I get `false` (and obviously, the same for `===`). If I then do `$instance->property = 'Edited'`, and then do `dd($instance->property, $second->property)`, I get `'Original'` and  `'Edited'` (two different values). So your question "Am I right or not?", your are not. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78194990/edit) and show your code? I'm curious about your approach and how you're seeing differing results.

Comment: I even tried with new instances, like `$instance = new Model()` (which initializes an empty Model), then `$second = $instance->replicate()`. `$instance == $second` is then `true` (since they're both empty and therefore equal), but (expectedly), `===` was `false` (different instances). I then did `property` editing and got the same results as above; editing one **did not** modify the other. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2AlQ.png.

Comment: Look at [the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/11.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1725). It just creates a new model and copies attributes from the old one as an array. Do you maybe have model attributes that are objects? I imagine they could still be linked afterwards.

Comment: How can you get "Original" if you do `$instance->property = 'Edited'`?